# Angular Problems

Tags: angular

I have a problem with a component in Angular, I'm trying to connect Angular with PHP.

I have this code in the app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticulosService } from './articulos.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-php';

  articulos = null;

  art = {
    codigo: null,
    descripcion: null,
    precio: null
  };

  constructor(private articulosServicio: ArticulosService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.MostrarTodos();
  }

  MostrarTodos(){
    this.articulosServicio.mostrarTodos().subscribe(result => this.articulos = result);
  }

  Agregar() {
    this.articulosServicio.agregar(this.art).subscribe(datos => {

        if (datos['resultado'] === 'OK') {
          alert(datos['mensaje']);
          this.MostrarTodos();
        }

      });
  }

  Eliminar(codigo) {
    this.articulosServicio.eliminar(codigo).subscribe(datos => {

      if (datos['resultado'] === 'OK') {
        alert(datos['mensaje']);
        this.MostrarTodos();  
      }

    });
  }

  Modificar() {
    this.articulosServicio.update(this.art).subscribe(datos => {

      if (datos['resultado'] === 'OK') {
        alert(datos['mensaje']);
        this.MostrarTodos();  
      }

    });
  }
}
```

And I have this two problems.

[First Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Grq.png)

[Second Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIoN.png)

I tried many things with this but and like I say I'm new in Angular.

If somebody can help me I will aprecciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript is your problem. You should probably google "beginner typescript tutorial".

Problem1:
When you write

```
  art = {
    codigo: null,
    descripcion: null,
    precio: null
  };
```

You are saying that codigo has *type* `null`. That's what `:` means.
It should be something like

```
 art = {
    codigo:string = null,
    descripcion:string = null,
    precio:string = null
  };
```

which means `codigo` has *type* string and *value* null

Problem2:
Angular doesn't know what *type* `datos` is.

Create a class/interface like this:

```
public class Datos{
  mensaje:string
  resultado:string
}
```

Use it like this:

```
  Agregar() {
this.articulosServicio.agregar(this.art).subscribe(datos:Datos => {

    if (datos.resultado === 'OK') {
      alert(datos.mensaje);
      this.MostrarTodos();
    }

  });
}
```